# redirect if url contains specific string using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect to different domain, `83answers.com` if url contains `forum` string.

Like if my url is `test.guru99.com/forum/xyxyxzz` then it should redirect to `83answers.com`. String forum can be anywhere in the url.

I have tried following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} forum
RewriteRule .* 83answers.com [R,L]
```

and also this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} forum
RewriteRule .* 83answers.com
```

But both didn't work ,Please help me to sort this out.

Regards

Answer (score 8):

For the base URL, you don't need `RewriteCond`, just `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule forum http://83answers.com [R,L]
```

For the query string, you were almost there:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} forum
RewriteRule .? http://83answers.com [R,L]
```

The combined rules:

```
RewriteRule forum http://83answers.com [R,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} forum
RewriteRule .? http://83answers.com [R,L]
```

Note that you must include `http://`. If you just use `83answers.com`, the server tries to redirect to a URL on your server. For example, it would redirect `http://test.guru99.com/forum/xyxyxzz` to `http://test.guru99.com/83answers.com`, which is no good.

Comment: I have put your code into htaccess but it's still not redirecting, i have also enabled the rewrite engine. Then i browsed to http://test.guru99.com/forum/5-faq/258-not-able-to-see-videos.html but it's not redirecting.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after enabling the rewrite engine?

Answer (score 3):

Real answer that i maded code is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)string(.*)$ http://your.website.com [R=301,L]
```

in place of **string** yoou can put your word

Comment: How can i get parameters eg. $1 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an OR clause between two RewriteCond like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} forum [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} forum
RewriteRule ^ http://83answers.com/? [L,R=301]
```