# Htaccess redirect if url contains a string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect url's who contains a string "cfg-contactform", the requested url contains sometimes mixed string like "cfg-contactform-15, 16, 22" etc... but I want to redirect all url's with string "cfg-contactform" including numbers or something others...

The solutions what I tried are:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24336/redirect-using-htaccess-if-a-url-contains-query-string

[htaccess redirect if URL contains a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220377/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-a-certain-string)

[redirect if url contains specific string using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521489/redirect-if-url-contains-specific-string-using-htaccess)

[htaccess redirect if URL contains a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220377/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-a-certain-string)

What I do wrong in my examples?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cfg-contactform
RewriteRule .? / [R,L]

or

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cfg-contactform [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} inc
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```